# Mario 1-up'd joke

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, jokes

I found a joke and I didn't get

> Girl1: For our anniversary my boyfriend took me to the mountains. 
>   Girl2: my boyfriend proposed me.
>   Girl2: they should call you Mario cause you just got 1-up'd.

I know the meaning of 1-up'd it means fighting and showing off and getting on top. But I still couldn't get the joke.

[Here is the joke](https://xkcd.com/151/)

Comment: In game, one-up means a life, so I think it means she got a new life. But, Im not sure about this. I also think it refers to a sexual joke.

Comment: @user178049 Heh, I wouldn't see anything sexual in this, but who knows.

Comment: Perhaps if the joke had been she'd gotten Princess Peached or something, then I could start to see more of a sexual innuendo :O :D. Speaking of which, that sounds like a pretty good phrase to start using.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang lol, I have a very dirty mind XD. Anyway, this question is very intriguing.

Comment: To be **one upped** means to be *outdone* by another person. Another person does something or says something that exceeds or outperforms your own attempt.   The way the term is used in the Mario game is not how it is used in typical contexts in English, where the person who is "one-upped" is not rewarded but the person with the lesser achievement.

Comment: It's worth noting that it should've been spelled *1-up'd* rather than *1up-d* which probably doesn't make as much sense. *1-up'd* makes sense because it turns *1-up* into a verb and then *'d* is added to make it a past participle.

Comment: @TRomano you are correct. The person is noting that the news shared by Girl1  was overshadowed by Girl2, who was also impolite enough to in effect say, "Ha ha! My news is better than yours." .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "they should call you Mario cause you just got 1up-d."

This is actually said by Girl2, as she has one upped Girl1 with a more impressive statement.

1UP in Mario refers to the extra life mushrooms that he collects, so in the game Mario gets "1-up'd" when he receives an extra life.

Girl1 has also been one upped, so Girl2 makes a joke that she should be called Mario.

(For any more XKCD comics you have trouble understanding, there is website dedicated to explaining them:
https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/151)